# How to add Google Maps data overlay to Openlayers map?

Tags: google-maps, javascript

So, for data purposes I want to use OpenLayers for my maps presentation but I want to use Google Maps as my data overlay or base layer. I know this is possible, but the UI isn't exactly friendly to new users.

As always, any advice is appreciated.

Comment: How do you know this is possible?  I believe using Google Maps data with another mapping software would be a violation of Google's TOS

Comment: Google, Bing and Yahoo all have commercial wms layers you can access through an api. I've used them with plain JavaScript open layers apps It's also in the examples...I'm just asking because it's not obvious through the Ui

Comment: Fair enough. Learned something new.  Looks like this is an example: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/google-map.html Map UI seems to lag a bit during movements, but UI widgets function

Comment: The question is specific to the Openlayers user interface, and has an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find OpenLayers for Drupal too daunting you could have a look at https://www.drupal.org/project/leaflet. It's easier to configure and more lightweight.

As for OpenLayers:

1. Create a view that provides an OpenLayers Data Overlay Display.
2. Then you may want to checkout: "admin/structure/openlayers/layers" and configure a Google Maps layer.
3. Then create a map over here "admin/structure/openlayers/maps". Make sure you enable your Google Maps layer as base and your Views Data Overlay as the Overlay for this map.
4. If you want to "show" the map also with Views create a new display (not an overlay) and use the OpenLayers Map formatter. You can then select your OL map created in step 3.

Comment: Hi dmshmidt, I'm interested in OL specifically because you can use multiple views as layers within a single map. Can you do this with leaflet too?

Comment: @nizz0k as far as I know Leaflet in Drupal doesn't allow you to use multiple data layers provided by Views.

Comment: any layering at all beyond locations and basemap?